# Radio checkboxes issue, don't work correctly?

Tags: radio-button, semantic-ui-react

I'm using Semantic-ui-React [library](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/checkbox) Trying to create Radio checkboxes,these checkboxes should be required. How can I do required for Radio buttons? Is there any way to make dropdown required in Semantic-ui-React?

```jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Divider,Label,List,Checkbox,Header } from 'semantic-ui-react'

handleRequest = (e, { value, label }) => {
  this.setState({ 
    redirect: false,
    requestCategory: value,
    typeOfRequest: label
  });
}

<Form.Field>
    <Form.Field>
      <Checkbox className = 'radio'
        required
        label="New Solution"
        name="typeOfRequest"
        value={false}
        checked={requestCategory === 'false'}
        onChange={this.handleRequest}
      />
    </Form.Field>
    <Form.Field>
      <Checkbox className = 'radio'
        required
        label="Enhancement to Existing Solution"
        name="typeOfRequest"
        value={'all'}
        checked={requestCategory === 'all'}
        onChange={this.handleRequest}
      />
    </Form.Field>
    <Form.Field>
      <Checkbox className = 'radio'
        required
        label="Production Support"
        name="typeOfRequest"
        value={'all'}
        checked={requestCategory === 'false'}
        onChange={this.handleRequest}
      />
    </Form.Field>
    <Form.Field>
      <Checkbox className = 'radio'
        required
        label="New Analysis"
        name="typeOfRequest"
        value={'all'}
        checked={requestCategory === 'all'}
        onChange={this.handleRequest}
      />
    </Form.Field>
    <Form.Field>
      <Checkbox className = 'radio'
       required
        label="Existing Analysis"
        name="typeOfRequest"
        value={'all'}
        checked={requestCategory === 'all'}
        onChange={this.handleRequest}
      />
    </Form.Field>
</Form.Field>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your checkbox field required, you just need to add the `required` props on the `<Form.Field>` component :

```js
<Form.Field required>
  <Checkbox
    radio
    label="Existing Analysis"
    name="typeOfRequest"
    value={'all'}
    checked={requestCategory === 'all'}
    onChange={this.handleRequest}
  />
</Form.Field>
```